# iptables - public IP vs private IP , accessible via public IP, but not with private IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, iptables

Initially with default iptables rules, EC2 Server A is able to access EC2 Server B via private IP.

Running `$ curl "http:<Server_B_private_IP>:80"` in Server A is successful.

Now in server B, I set rules to allow only Server A(using public IP) and block rest of the traffic.

Running `$ curl "http:<Server_B_public_IP>:80"` in server A is successful but `$ curl "http:<Server_B_private_IP>:80"` is failing.

Is this normal? Why server B is able to recognise server A via public ip, but not with private_ip?

Comment: You said that you "set rules to allow only Server A(using public IP) and block rest of the traffic", so why are you asking why it doesn't work via Private IP? Isn't that what you configured?

Comment: Yeah, but I still gave whole access to Server A, meaning it should be able to access Server B with private or public IP, right? But that's not the case.

Comment: Can you show us your IP Tables configuration? If Server A goes to the public address of Server B, then the traffic will be coming from the Public IP address of Server A. If it is going to the private IP address of Server B within the same VPC, then Server A will be coming from its private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of your rules is bad. Change the order. Put your "allow" rule before and the restricting rule at the end.